# Difference between filter and find in Sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am not clear with these two term

Filter : List out all records with match of 3 characters, where as

Find : Retrieve exact match record.

Correct me if am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter method returns all records of store which match to your given fields and value.
find method returns you index of your first match record of your given fields and value.

Comment: This is true, but filter does more than just return matches; it will also affect any components to which the store is bound. filter() also affects most of the methods on the store to deal with only the filtered records, and filter() also announces a slew of events.